# line in vue.js function executed before the previous ended

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following function to submit a form:

```
methods: {
  submit_form: function () {
    this.drawing = dat.toImage();
    this.$refs.my_form.submit()
  }
}
```

The `drawing` variable is assigned to an input within `my_form` like:

```
<input type="text" name="doodle" :value="drawing">
```

The issue is that the form is being sent before `this.drawing` is updated with the value of `dat.toImage()`. Indeed, if I split the previous function into two:

```
methods: {
  submit_form: function () {
    this.$refs.my_form.submit()
  },
  set_drawing: function () {
    this.drawing = dat.toImage()
  }
}
```

when I run first `set_drawing()` and then `submit_form()` (with two different buttons), then the form is correctly sent with the updated drawing value. Thus, for some reason, when both lines are in the same function, the form is being sent before the execution of the previous line is ended.

Any idea about why is this happening and how to solve it?

UPDATE:

This does not work either, the null value is sent with the form.

```
data: {
  drawing: null
}
methods: {
  submit_form: function () {
    this.drawing = dat.toImage();
    while (this.drawing == null) {
      false
    }
    this.$refs.my_form.submit()
  }
}
```

It seems that whatever value I initialize `drawing` with, is the value sent with the form. Indeed I am also displaying the value of `drawing` in the website, and I see it changes when I hit submit, but the loop above never ends.

The `.toImage` method belongs to the atrament.js library.

Also, to catch the submit event I do:

```
<form method="POST" class="model-form" v-on:submit.prevent="submit_form()" ref="my_form">
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `dat.toImage()` is an asynchronous method, so Javascript start executing next method while this is not yet done. If this is your own method, you can return a promise from this function and on resolve of this promise invoke your second method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did some more experiments to check if this could be the root of the issue, but it doesn't seem so. I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: @user1294122 I dont see you using promises in the edited version, You can see an example [here](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises) on how to use it.

Comment: @user1294122 In the update, you're making the exactly same mistake [I made once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210242/whilecount-3-fail-to-check-callback-state), thinking javascript would excute the callback code *the moment* the async job fulfills, but in fact, js checks if there's some callback to excute every time it reaches the end of a function, thus a while loop, misused by both of us, would not work the way we want.